# How would I change this code to make it so that it asks me the location of the file that I want to load?

Tags: java

So my code currently has the user specify the name of the file that they want to load within the code itself but how would I make it so that when the program is run then the user will enter the location of the file that they want to load?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class reader {

    static int validresults = 0;
    static int invalidresults = 0;
    //used to count the number of invalid and valid matches

    public static boolean verifyFormat(String[] words) {
        boolean valid = true;
        if (words.length != 4) { 
            valid = false;
        } else if (words[0].isEmpty() || words[0].matches("\\s+")) {
            valid = false;
        } else if ( words[1].isEmpty() || words[1].matches("\\s+")) {
            valid = false;
        }

        return valid && isInteger(words[2]) && isInteger(words[3]);}

    //checks to see that the number of items in the file are equal to the four needed and the last 2 are integers
    //also checks to make sure that there are no results that are just whitespace

    public static boolean isInteger( String input ) {
        try {
            Integer.parseInt( input );
            return true;
        }
        catch( Exception e ) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    //checks to make sure that the data is an integer

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        String hteam;
        String ateam;
        int hscore;
        int ascore;
        int totgoals = 0;

        Scanner s = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(
                new FileReader("fbscores.txt"))).useDelimiter("\\s*:\\s*|\\s*\\n\\s*");

        while (s.hasNext()) {
            String line = s.nextLine();
            String[] words = line.split("\\s*:\\s*");
            //splits the file at colons

            if(verifyFormat(words)) {
                hteam = words[0];       // read the home team
                ateam = words[1];       // read the away team
                hscore = Integer.parseInt(words[2]);       //read the home team score
                totgoals = totgoals + hscore;
                ascore = Integer.parseInt(words[3]);       //read the away team score
                totgoals = totgoals + ascore;
                validresults = validresults + 1;

                System.out.println(hteam + " " +  "[" + hscore + "]" +  " " + ateam + " " + "[" + ascore + "]");   
                //output the data from the file in the format requested

            }
            else{
                invalidresults = invalidresults + 1;
            }
        }
    System.out.println("Total number of goals scored was " + totgoals);
    //displays the the total number of goals
    System.out.println("Valid number of games is " + validresults);
    System.out.println("Invalid number of games is " + invalidresults);

        System.out.println("EOF");
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6091087/how-to-get-open-file-popup

Comment: Your main method takes an array of strings as parameters - you can make use of it. Read about the [command line args](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html).

Comment: Please use formatter and stick to some basic naming conventions.

Comment: Actively defacing your own question after you have asked and received an answer it goes against the spirit of StackOverflow. As such, I have rolled back your edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to use a main loop asking for a file name and quitting program execution when no input is given.

Therefore I'd refactor most code of your `main` method into another function e.g. `processFile(String fileName)`.

Then your `main` only deals with user input

```
public static void main(String args[]){
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
  while(true){ //keep running till we break

    System.out.println("Enter filename or return blank line to quit");
    String fileName = sc.nextLine();

    if(fileName != null && !fileName.isEmpty()){ 
      processFile(fileName)
    }else{
      break; //no user input => exit
    }
  }
  System.out.println("bye");
}

private static processFile(String fileName){
    String hteam;
    String ateam;
    int hscore;
    int ascore;
    int totgoals = 0;

    Scanner s = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(
            new FileReader(fileName))).useDelimiter("\\s*:\\s*|\\s*\\n\\s*");

    while (s.hasNext()) {
      … //rest of your original code
}
```

Comment: With that I understand how it works but I don't know how I would format my code so that it would work in the way that you've written it. I've worded that awfully but I can't figure out where I would insert my code to make it so that it works because when I put the code in it just ends up breaking my code, could you show me where it would be inserted?